# Cannot install MSMQ

Tags: windows-xp, msmq

I'm trying to install MSMQ on some of our WinXP computers. However, in all cases the installation fails.

I go to Control Panel > Add/Remove Programs > Add/Remove Windows Components. I check "Message Queueing" and then click "Next". It prompts me for the Windows XP SP3 CD, and this is where the problem starts

I have a Windows XP SP2 CD, but this didn't work. So I downloaded an ISO for Windows XP SP3 CD, and that doesn't work either. I insert the CD into the drive and click "Ok", and the dialog box pops right back up.

I need to get this service installed. Any ideas about how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you point the installer to the i386 folder on the CD?  You can usually browse or type the UNC path This usually works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I'm concerned that you were prompted to insert the CD at all. The MSMQ files should all be in place in Windows, waiting for you to enable Message Queuing. This was introduced after the pain caused in Windows 2000 by the install files only being on the CD.

If I have the time on Friday, I'll test this problem out on my Windows XP machines.

Cheers
John Breakwell (MSFT)

Comment: Apparently it's broken on windows server 2019 too as the Powershell command:  Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName MSMQ-Server -All    .... breaks with "The referenced assembly could not be found". This is a clean Azure VM, I ran SFC and DISM over it too to ensure there was nothing wrong system wise.