# Cannot install MSMQ on Azure Based Windows server 2019 machine

Tags: installation, windows-server-2019, msmq

Fairly new VM
I've only added IIS to it and pushed some web app source code.
Then I run the powershell command ...

```
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName MSMQ-Server -All
```

to support some legacy app functionality but was met with the error ...

```
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature : The referenced assembly could not be found.
At line:1 char:1
+ Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName MSMQ-Server -All
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Dism.Commands.EnableWindowsOptionalFeatureCommand
```

I noticed these ...

- [Cannot install MSMQ](https://superuser.com/questions/81487/cannot-install-msmq#_=)_
- https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/WSL/issues/368

... but no luck solving the problem and i'm not convinced how related they are given the differences in each.

The regular process (like this: https://support.mailessentials.gfi.com/hc/en-us/articles/360015143519--Installing-MSMQ-on-Windows-Server-2016) of going through the "Programs & Features" GUI produces the same error.

I have run the following commands to ensure that the system isn't broken in some way but they didn't find any issues ...

```
sfc /scannow
dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /CheckHealth
```

Is there a way to manually install (perhaps an MSI download or something)?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this functionality is now deprecated, older OS versions still support it but Server 2019 doesn't appear to so state of the art VM's deployed to Azure won't support MSMQ at all.

In my case this is not the end of the world, I was able to re-implement a single interface in my code stack and retire it entirely but others out there may not be so lucky.

Given the nature of the problem I faced I had raised a priority A ticket with Azure support, some 5 later they came back to say "i've got no solutions for you".

I had already done the rewrite on my end to avoid the problem, but this is very telling.

Anyone out there using MSMQ, deploy server 2016 or earlier OS'es if you need it of if like me you can code it out i'd suggest that or replace the need for MSMQ with Azure Queues or something.